# how to specify a filename pattern for tests in android-unit-test?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-testing

is there a way to specify a pattern for android-unit-test? at the moment it seems to be `*Test.class`, but I would like it to be `The*.class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that seems to do the trick:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    scanForTestClasses = false
    include "**/*The*.class" // whatever Ant pattern matches your test class files
}
```